# How to return values from query when joining multiple tables in Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Linq queries that have tables join and couple of tables inner join together. Sometimes I got an error from the query when table is empty. What I trying to do is I  am tryting to get a value from table even if other table is empty.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do left join
Assuming left join between customer and order table.

```
var query =
    from customer in dc.Customers
    from order
    in dc.Orders
         .Where(o => customer.CustomerId == o.CustomerId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Customer = customer, Order = order }
```

Also refer below link
http://forums.asp.net/t/1792428.aspx/1